# Problem with bibliography after updating to TeX Live 2013

Tags: biblatex, texlive, biber

I update today to TeX Live 2013 (MacTeX) from TeX Live 2012. On my `.tex` document (that was perfectly working until yesterday) I run and get in the mini-buffer:

1) `latex` -> `You should run Biber to get citation right` (This is new, yesterday it asked me for BibLaTeX...)

2) `biber` -> `Biber finished successfully. Run LaTex again to get citations right`

3) `latex` -> `LaTeX: There were unresolved citations`

I did update with TeX Live Utility all the packages, I restarted my Mac. Still same problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Set the values for the biblography
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
]{biblatex}

%Point to the bibliography db
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{egghead2013} 

\textcite[][361]{egghead2013} %three times, on more pages...

\end{document}
```

This is my output after the last step:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `document' with ``pdflatex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" document.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(./document.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty 
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex2.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplotstable.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex
Package pgfplots: loading complementary code for your PGF version...

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_misc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgfcorelayers.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststructure.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststructureext.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsarray.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsmatrix.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstableshared.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsdeque.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.data.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.verb.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.
code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstackedplots.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scaling.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstable.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstable.coltype.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(./document.aux (./bib/egghead2013.aux))
(./document.bbl) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} into your preamble.
 on input line 38.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./bib/egghead2013.tex

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'egghead2013' on page 2 undefined on input line 1.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'egghead2013' on page 2 undefined on input line 16.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'egghead2013' on page 2 undefined on input line 16.


Overfull \hbox (2.80838pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 30--32
 [][] 

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'egghead2013' on page 2 undefined on input line 32.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'egghead2013' on page 2 undefined on input line 32.


Overfull \hbox (14.48819pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 45--47
 [][] 

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'egghead2013' on page 2 undefined on input line 47.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'egghead2013' on page 2 undefined on input line 47.

) [2] [3] (./document.aux (./bib/egghead2013.aux))

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                document
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx8.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbxti10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt12.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (3 pages, 112516 bytes).
SyncTeX written on document.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on document.log.

LaTeX finished at Wed Aug 14 09:07:38
```

And finally my output after `biber`:

```
Running `Biber' on `document' with ``biber document''
INFO - This is Biber 1.7
INFO - Logfile is 'document.blg'
INFO - Reading 'document.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'mybib.bib' for section 0
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'mybib.bib'

Biber abort trap: 6 at Wed Aug 14 09:33:22
```

And running `biber --debug document.bcf` from shell I get the same

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.7
INFO - Logfile is 'document.blg'
INFO - DEBUG mode: all messages are logged to 'document.blg'
INFO - Reading 'document.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'mybib.bib' for section 0
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'mybib.bib'
zsh: abort      biber --debug document.bcf
```

Comment: `biber` is completing successfully and the output ends with the line: `Biber abort trap: 6 at Wed Aug 14 09:33:22`?

Comment: Exactly. "Biber finished successfully. Run LaTex again to get citations right" is what I get in the little-buffer after running biber. And that other is the "Output Buffer".

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant mini-buffer (for little-buffer). I edited the question adding the result from running --debug from command line. I doesn't add anything.

Comment: document.blg is exactly as the output from biber --debug document.bcf I posted. Just the last line is missing (zsh: abort      biber --debug document.bcf). I also tried biber --debug --trace document.bcf. Same output.

Comment: The long file for me is .bcf not .blg. In .bcf indeed I get all the attempts to cache my .bib file.

Comment: Then I think `biber` is aborting too soon.  Actually, your last INFO message is only about halfway through the normal output.  Normally, it should end with lines like: `INFO - Writing '<file>.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'` and `INFO - Output to <file>.bbl`.  (I'm deleting my earlier comments, since they are unlikely to be helpful in the future.)

Comment: We need a full MWE with your .bib to see what's happening.

Comment: Also, the "--debug" option to biber won't change the terminal output - it increases the logging in the .blg log file.

Comment: I think I sorted out where the problem is. Biber aborts only when I use mybib.bib file. If I change the \addbibresource  with a test bibliography it all works fine. Also mybib.bib works just fine with BibTex. What could be the compatibility problem between mybib.bib and Biber? (mybib.bib was exported by Zotero).

Answer (score 1):

I kind of fix the problem simply by replacing `backend=biber` with `backend=bibtex` and then run "Bibtex" instead of "Biber". I got the pdf output then with all the references right.